# Javascript ORing in variable how it works?

Tags: javascript

I want to know the process of ORing in javascript variable. I used below code for just testing purpose. I want just know the process behind these ORing in var. I know the process when we are using in if condition. Please any one explain me in details.

```
var a = a || "2010" || "Gunjan" || 20;
console.log(a);
//output 2010
```

When I console var `a` then it gives me output like `2010`.

1. Why?
2. How?
3. Can anyone one explain me background process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) returns the value of one of the operands, so if the operands returns a non boolean value then the logical operation could return a non boolean value

> Logical operators are typically used with Boolean (logical) values.
>   When they are, they return a Boolean value. However, the && and ||
>   operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands,
>   so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may
>   return a non-Boolean value.

Also looking at [Short-Circuit Evaluation](http://Short-Circuit%20Evaluation), the [OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_(.7C.7C)) will stop executing of further conditions once one of the operands is true.

Now looking at your condition `var a = a || "2010" || "Gunjan" || 20;`, since you have used `var a`, I'm assuming you are declaring the variable `a` here, so when the RHS is executed `a` has a value `undefined` which is falsy so the OR operator executes the second operand which is a string literal `2010` which is a non boolean but truthy value so that is returned as a result of this operations

Comment: After 2nd true value these can't execute ? Am i right ?

Comment: @higunjan the statements `|| "Gunjan" || 20` won't be executed

Answer (score 1):

Oring will return the first true value or the last value if all are false.
True value means not null,not undefined,not 0 ,not empty etc.

Comment: Well,can i get some reputation?@Arun P Johny,excellent but you've got enough.